# Complexity of inverting and multiplying against a symmetric Toeplitz matrix with two repeated entries

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-inverse, circulant-matrices

I know that the computational complexity of inverting a general $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is $O(n^{2.373})$ and multiplying it against an $n \times m$ matrix is $O(n^2m)$.  Moreover, I've seen that special matrices, such as upper-triangular matrices, admit algorithms for computing these basic operations which are much faster.

In my case, I have an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A$ with *two entries* $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $A_{i,i}=\alpha$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $A_{i,j}=\beta$ for $i,j=1,\dots,n$ with $i\neq j$. That is
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha &\beta &\dots& \beta \\
\beta & \alpha & \dots &\beta \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \\
\beta & \dots & & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
My intuition is that these operations should be of near linear complexity in $n$, in this case, since the operations should only depend on $n$ basic operations with two constants, $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

So my question is: For such a matrix, what are the most efficient known algorithms for computing matrix inversion and multiplication?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Gray's [Toeplitz and Circulant Matrices](https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.html)

Answer (score 3):

When your data have such strong structure, questions of "computational complexity" can be drastically affected on *how you encode input and output*, and also on which parameters you hold constant.

### Inversion

The actual calculation (see below) can be done in a constant number of scalar operations, so can we simply say the time complexity is constant?

**First consider the input method.** Since we know the structure, you might give the input as the triple $(n,\alpha,\beta)$. Or, if you present the input matrix explicitly, for example in row-major form, it suffices to read the first two entries to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Oh, but you need to know also $n$. Was it a constant, or given as a separate input, or do you need to read a full row of input to find how long it is?

**Then consider the actual calculation.**
Knowing $(\alpha, \beta, n)$, we only need a constant number of scalar arithmetic operations. We observe that
$$A = (\alpha-\beta) I + \beta uu^T,$$
where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix and $u$ is the $n \times 1$ vector of ones. Then, by the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) and some simplification, every diagonal entry of $A^{-1}$ is
$$
c - c^2 \beta / (1+nc\beta)
$$
and every off-diagonal entry is
$$
 - c^2 \beta / (1+nc\beta)
$$
where we have written $c = 1/(\alpha-\beta)$ for brevity. (It might simplify even further, I didn't check.)

**Then consider the output method.** We know from above that the output matrix has just two different values: on-diagonal and off-diagonal. We computed them in constant time (assuming constant-time scalar arithmetic). Can we output it in constant time? Yes, if we are only required to output the two values and if outputting a scalar is constant-time. But if explicit $n \times n$ output matrix is required, surely that lower-bounds the output time. Also, note that the size of the scalars depends on the values of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $n$. Do you need to output them as exact rationals? Floating point approximation?

### Multiplication

You did not stipulate any special structure in the second ($n \times m$) matrix. Assuming constant-time scalar operations, the straightforward $O(nm)$ method is optimal. This is a lower bound because just outputting the $n \times m$ result takes this much.

From the inversion section we recall
$$A = (\alpha-\beta) I + \beta uu^T.$$
Multiplying by the first term is multiplying your second matrix by a scalar. Multiplying by the second term is taking column sums and multiplying by scalar. Each part, and adding them, is easily done in $O(nm)$ time.

### Appendix

This kind of matrix (constant value on main diagonal, another constant everywhere else) has been called *double-constant matrix*, at least by Ben O'Neill in his 2021 arXiv manuscript ([The Double-Constant Matrix, Centering Matrix and Equicorrelation Matrix: Theory and Applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.05814)). This may lead to further information. On page 9 there is a formula for the inverse matrix, similar to mine above.

Another name seems to be *completely symmetric matrix*, e.g. Henderson (1981), [C85. On the inverse of a completely symmetric matrix](https://doi.org/10.1080/00949658108810443), Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation 12: 138-139.